# How to set a base URI and prepend it to all href in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, uri

I'm developing a multilingual web application in ASP.Net and C# without using MVC. On first visit the user has to choose language. Country and city as optional. The page will then redirect by appending the language, country and city to the host name.

For example, if the host name is

```
http://example.com
```

the page will be redirected as

```
http://example.com/en/us/new-york
```

There are diffrent pages in the application like home, gallery, products, features  etc. I want to prepend the URL with language, country and city to all the URL's in the application

```
http://example.com/en/us/new-york/home
http://example.com/en/us/new-york/gallery
http://example.com/en/us/new-york/products
```

I want to make `http://example.com/en/us/new-york/` as a base URI or set it as a global variable to prepend it to the href

In some cases the user may not select country or city. Then the base URI should be

```
http://example.com/en/home
http://example.com/en/us/gallery
http://example.com/en/us/features
```

I've created a function in a class so that I can use the function in both Master page as well as Child page.

```
public class urls
{
    public static string PrependURL(string Language, string Country, string City)
    {
        StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder("/");
        if (Country == "" && City == "")
            url.Append(Language);
        else if (Country != "" && City == "")
            url.Append(Language).Append("/").Append(Country);
        else if (Country != "" && City != "")
            url.Append(Language).Append("/").Append(Country).Append("/").Append(City);
        return url.ToString();
    }
}
```

and use that function as

```
<a href="<%= urls.PrependURL(Request.QueryString["language"].ToString(), Request.QueryString["country"].ToString(), Request.QueryString["city"].ToString()) %>/home">Home</a>
<a href="<%= urls.PrependURL(Request.QueryString["language"].ToString(), Request.QueryString["country"].ToString(), Request.QueryString["city"].ToString()) %>/products">Products</a>
<a href="<%= urls.PrependURL(Request.QueryString["language"].ToString(), Request.QueryString["country"].ToString(), Request.QueryString["city"].ToString()) %>/features">Features</a>
```

I don't want to call one function several times. How to set it as a global varaible so that I can append it as

```
<a href="<%= globalBaseURI %>/home">Home</a>
<a href="<%= globalBaseURI %>/features">Features</a>
```

I've tried to used the public variable from C# code behind. But can't access it.

Comment: why don't you just add the country as a querystring? `www.example.com/home?lang=us`

Comment: Well I'm using Intelligencia URL Rewriter. I need to use http://example.com/en/us/new-york/home
to render as http://example.com/index.aspx?language=en&country=us&city=new-york.